# Annotation definition with multiple parameters

Tags: java, annotations

There are two parameters in the definition, `value` and `optional`.
but in the usage, there is only one parameter, so I have two questions:

1. If there are less parameters in usage than in definition, and the parameter name is absent, how to determine which one is used?
2. In the above code, value is an array type, but `AuthRequired.AuthType.Server` is an element, how can they match?

There is an annotation definition:

Java Code:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface AuthRequired {
    enum AuthType {
        Server(null),
        Student(UserType.Student),
        Teacher(UserType.Teacher),
        SchoolMaster(UserType.SchoolMaster),
        Operator(UserType.Operator);

        private UserType userType;

        AuthType(UserType userType) {
            this.userType = userType;
        }

        public UserType getUserType() {
            return userType;
        }
    }

    AuthType[] value() default {};

    boolean optional() default false;

}
```

And its usage:

Java Code:

```
@AuthRequired(AuthRequired.AuthType.Server)
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/isUserSlaveOf")
boolean isUserSlaveOf(
@RequestParam String slaveUserIds,
...
...
```

Comment: They match by type

Comment: The only way in which the field name can be absent is if the field name is `value`. All other fields must be named. The special name `value` is the "default" one.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you do not specify the parameter name, it's always the `value` parameter that's used. Also this is only legal, if you specify a single parameter. Otherwise you need to use `<parameterName>=<value>` for each parameter.
2. Instead of specifying a single element array using the `{}` bracket notation you are also allowed to simply write the element. `@AuthRequired(value=AuthRequired.AuthType.Server)` is equivalent to `@AuthRequired(value={AuthRequired.AuthType.Server})`.